# How to get only the changed values in ngrx selector?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

**Working on angular application using ngrx**

Lets say I have a bunch of cards on the UI that can either be in expanded or collapsed state.
So I keep track of what is open/close in an object:

```js
export interface MyAppState {
  cardStates: {[key: string] : boolean}  // true = card is expanded, false = card is collapsed
}
```

Now in UI when a expanded card is clicked, it must be collapsed and similarly when a collapsed card is clicked it must be expanded.
In .html file of the component

```html
<card (click)="changeState(card.id)">
```

In .ts file of the component

```js
constructor(private store: Store<MyAppState>) {
  store.select(selectors.selectCardStates).subscribe((cardStates) => {
    for (let key in cardStates) {
      if (cardStates[key] // ...code to open the card in the ui
      else // ...code to close the card in the ui
    }
  }
}

changeState(cardId: string) {
  this.store.dispatch(actions.changeCardState({ carId }))
}
```

In reducer.ts file

```js
//... Other boiler plate
switch(changeCardState.type):
  const cardStates = deepcopy(state.cardStates)
  cardStates[action.cardId] = !cardStates[action.cardId] 
  return { cardStates }
```

In selectors.ts file

```js
export const selectCardStates = (state) => state.cardStates
```

So whenever changeCardState action is dispatched I  get the latest cardStates object in my component via the selectCardStates selector. But I have no way of knowing what exactly was changed in the the cardStates object!
So the code i wrote inside subscribe in component.ts file, should actually be like this:

```js
store.select(selectors.selectCardStates).subscribe((cardStates) => {
    const cardsWhoseStateChangeIds = []  // somehow need this
    for (let key of cardsWhoseStateChangeIds ) {
      if (cardStates[key] // ...code to open the card in the ui
      else // ...code to close the card in the ui 
    }
  }
```

One way I know is to keep a copy of cardstates in my component and compare the new value inside subscribe with this local copy and figure out what changed. But it looks like to much work just to get the information which I already had (I know what card state was changed in changeState() function), but it seems to have lost after going through all the ngrx state management stuff.
Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: One way around this could be change the UI in `changeState` before dispatching the new state to RxJs.

Comment: Can do that but what if the reducer had some logic that prevented state change in certain scenarios, then doing this would not work.

Answer (score 1):

I am quite sure that this is something you have to track yourself, afaik no built-in helper exists for that.

But why not extend your state?

```
export interface MyAppState {
  lastCardId: string;
  cardStates: {[key: string] : boolean} 
}
```

You already have the cardId in your action, so the changes to the reducer should be no big deal.